# Reverse image load order?

Tags: android

**First Question**

I use [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) to load images in a ListView and a GridView.  It works but the images are loaded form bpttom to top. How to fix that?

**Bonus Question**

Can I use a loading animation in a image view while the real image is loaded?  Right now it's just a default image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageLoader.java you could replace

```
photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
```

with

```
photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.get(0);
photosQueue.photosToLoad.remove(photoToLoad);
```

It will change the order.

To display ProgressBar you can just add it to item.xml. Initially ProgressBar is visible and image is hidden. After bitmap is downloaded you hide ProgressBar and show image. But I would not recommend doing that. While images are being decoded in the background they consume processor power and all your progress bars may be freezing sometimes.